# Arial font not working on PDF file on ubuntu

Tags: pdf, fonts, pdf-to-html

I have a PDF which shows properly on the browser but some text is not showing on the PDF viewer on on UBUNTU, I checked the fonts of the pdf and it return

```
Syntax Error: non-embedded font using identity encoding: Arial-BoldMT
Syntax Error: non-embedded font using identity encoding: ArialMT
```

I tried to add font substitute but it is not working.

The actual text is

```
Benefits (After 90 Days Full Time)
```

but it shows like following

```
Benefits (After 90 Days)XOO7LPH)
```

I have installed arial font on ubuntu also but its still not working.

Please help.

UPDATE : The file is showing properly on adobe pdf viewer and browsers but not on ubuntu.

Comment: @KJ it shows properly on the browser and adobe pdf reader but not on ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be a bug in Firefox.

See https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1766039.
The same bug was also reported in pdf.js github https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/issues/15317